# gradle: calling a task from another task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am aware that the currently supported method for invoking a task from another task is to use `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`, but I run into an issue with this.

I have a task, `taskA`, that is usable on it's own.  I have another task, `taskB`, which, when called, will depend upon `taskA`.  The problem is that `taskB` has additional conditions that require the task be skipped if they fail. Here is the workflow I am going for:

```
$ gradle taskA
:taskA

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
$ gradle taskB
checking condition 1... PASS
checking condition 2... PASS
:taskA
:taskB

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
$ gradle taskB
checking condition 1... PASS
checking condition 2... FAIL
:taskA SKIPPED
:taskB SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

If called directly, or as a `doFirst` or `dependsOn` or something from a different task, `taskA` should execute regardless of the conditions.  But if `taskB` is called, the conditions must pass before `taskA` is executed.  Here's what I've tried:

```
project.tasks.create(name: "taskB", type: MyTask, dependsOn: "taskA")
project.taskB{
  onlyIf {
    if (!conditionA()){
      return false
    }
    if (!conditionB()){
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

The problem here is that `taskA` will execute before the `onlyIf` is checked on `taskB`, so even if a condition fails, `taskA` will execute.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that it can be configured no sooner than after task's graph has been resolved. At the earlier stages all conditions will be evaluated on *configuration* phase which is too early. Have a look at this:

```
task a {
  doLast {
      println 'a'
  }
}

task b {
  dependsOn a
  doLast {
      println 'b'
  }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(b)) {
        a.enabled = b.enabled = check1() && check2()
    }
}

boolean check1() {
  def ok = project.hasProperty('c')
  println "check 1: ${ok ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL'}"
  ok
}

boolean check2() {
  def ok = project.hasProperty('d')
  println "check 2: ${ok ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL'}"
  ok
}
```

And the output:

```
 ~/tutorial/stackoverflow/40850083/ [master] gradle a
:a
a

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.728 secs

 ~/tutorial/stackoverflow/40850083/ [master] gradle b
check 1: FAIL
:a SKIPPED
:b SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.739 secs

 ~/tutorial/stackoverflow/40850083/ [master] gradle b -Pc
check 1: PASS
check 2: FAIL
:a SKIPPED
:b SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.714 secs

 ~/tutorial/stackoverflow/40850083/ [master] gradle b -Pc -Pd
check 1: PASS
check 2: PASS
:a
a
:b
b

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.745 secs
```

Comment: where does the `gradle` variable come from?

Comment: possibly worth noting that this does not take place in my `build.gradle` file.  This is in a separate Groovy file that configures the plugin

Comment: @ewok, a separate groovy file that configures the plugin? How does it work? `gradle` is defined on `project` instance as all other variables that are taken out of nowhere ;)

Comment: I call `apply plugin` from build.gradle, which executes `apply()` on the plugin. that method calls `new PluginConfigurator().configure(project)`.  the `PluginConfigurator.configure()` method is where the configuration is done.  it takes 1 argument of type `org.gradle.api.Project`.  When I try to add the code you suggested to that method, I get `No such property: gradle for class: plugin.PluginConfigurator`

Comment: @ewok, please rephrase you question in such a way that it will represent a real problem. Otherwise it might be difficult to help.

Comment: @ewok, don't give up. Try once again ;) You mentioned a plugin and there's no plugin in your question.

Comment: honestly I'm not even sure what that means.  I have been having a lot of trouble understanding Gradle sometimes.  What is missing from my question?

Comment: @ewok, well, I don't know. On the other hand I may ask what is missing in my answer since as far as I see it didn't answer your question. Is my answer bad or your question wasn't precise enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129265/discussion-between-opal-and-ewok).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not recommended by most people, but I did it by actually executing a task, thusly:

```
task a {
  doLast {
      println 'a'
  }
}

task b {
  doLast {
      a.execute()
      println 'b'
  }

  outputs.upToDateWhen {
    conditionA() && conditionB()
  }
}
```

Comment: `execute` should never be called directly.

Comment: So they say. I don't really follow coding fundamentalism. Rules with "shouldn't" indicate when you're breaking a paradigm, but sometimes breaking a paradigm is the easiest way to do something.

Comment: _The easiest_ possibility doesn't mean it should be followed. Also, this is not a problem of paradigm or not - but spoiling gradle internals.

Comment: Feel free to give an actual reason why calling `execute` is a bad idea.

Comment: "Feel free to give an actual reason why calling execute is a bad idea": Because `execute` was deprecated and no longer exists...

Comment: Unfortunately for me, `execute` does now no longer exist!